# Compile-time: count #(~N) of members of type X and define a member array[N]?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, counter, compile-time

Is there a way to count number of members in struct (ints in the below example) at compile time and define an array of same size in the same struct? Using a MACRO or a templated struct instead of the int type would be OK.

```
struct A
{
    int myInts[numInts()];  // here numInts() == 2
    int a;
    char b;
    char c;
    int d;
    char e;
};
```

I feel it may be possible with some constexpr hacks but haven't found a solution. What I need is to create an array where I can compact a copy of all the members to and the array needs to be statically allocated at compile time. Number of members will differ from a struct to struct, but the array should grow automatically to have space for all the members of interest. Also to make the matters worse, the array needs to be defined before the other members.

====== Edit

It seems there isn't a solution that does above without over-complicating struct design overall. Instead, I went with a need to specify array size manually.

Comment: You can do it after you've defined the struct using various "struct to tuple using structured bindings" tricks

Comment: Why would you want an array of the same size? Expand on the reason why you want this and perhaps we can offer alternatives.

Comment: I need a compact storage for a copy of all the ints that are part of the struct (and any ints within any sub-struct members) as they all are copied from and to as a contiguous memory block at once. The reason why all the ints can't be defined together is that some of the ints come in as sub-members of other struct members (i.e. struct substruct{ char a; int b;}; hence they become interleaved in memory. The struct can have quite a few non-int members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be approched using [MAP-MACRO](https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro) and some templates.
You need to define your structs using a macro and pass all fields to it(eg. `DEFINE_STRUCT(A, int a, char b, ...)`). The number of `int`(or another type you want) fields can be counted by applying recursive template on a helper function of type `void(int a, char b, ...)`. MAP-MACRO is needed for appending semicolons after each field.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include "map-macro/map.h" // https://github.com/swansontec/map-macro, we need the `MAP` macro


// Count how many arguments of Func are of type T

template<typename T, typename Func>
struct count_of_type;

template<typename T>
struct count_of_type<T, void()> { static constexpr std::size_t value = 0; };

template<typename T, typename FirstArg, typename...RestArgs>
struct count_of_type<T, void(FirstArg, RestArgs...)> {
  static constexpr std::size_t value = std::is_same<T, FirstArg>::value + count_of_type<T, void(RestArgs...)>::value;
};


// Define your structs

#define APPEND_SEMICOLON(FIELD) FIELD;

#define DEFINE_STRUCT(NAME, FIELDS, ...) \
  struct NAME { \
    int myInts[count_of_type<int, void(FIELDS, ##__VA_ARGS__)>::value]; \
    MAP(APPEND_SEMICOLON, FIELDS, ##__VA_ARGS__) \
  };

DEFINE_STRUCT(A,
    int a,
    char b,
    char c,
    int d,
    char e)

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(A().myInts), int[2]>::value, "");
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I believe this provides a solution to my problem, but it's not a solution I can use for my use case. In my case, the point of avoiding needing to specify # of occurrences of a type is to lower the development complexity of supporting countable complex types and make the count automatic. However, specifying # of complex types ahead or on complex type change is better than making structs less maintainable / harder to work with which wrapping whole struct does. Thank you regardless, I think this is as best as it gets to what I envisioned!

Answer (score 3):

It's possible for some types using the [magic_get library](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get). The limitation is:

> T must be constexpr aggregate initializable and must not contain references nor bitfields

The struct `A` in your post satisfies this condition.

`magic_get` detects the number of non-static data members using aggregate initialization. Basically, the idea is that if you have some type `U` that can convert to any other type, then `T{U(), U(), ..., U()}` will be well-formed when the number of `U()`s equals the number of elements in the aggregate `T`. (If `T` has some members that have a default member initializer or can be value-initialized, this expression may also be well-formed when there are fewer initializers than elements, so you have to take the maximum number that works.) And SFINAE can be used to detect whether such an expression is well-formed or not.

You can see all the gory details in [fields_count.hpp](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get/blob/develop/include/boost/pfr/detail/fields_count.hpp)

Comment: It would require complete class, so cannot be used to **define** A member, just to check it.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point. I didn't read carefully enough